# cannot access the file because it is using by another program Error

Tags: c#-4.0

I have been fighting with this issue since last week.still not able to solve.
i am sending file to client machine once i get in server automatically.but so many time when i handle file it throw an error that Cannot access the file because it is using by another program.

below my code

```
private static string SaveFileStream(string filePath, Stream stream, string Filename1)
{

    string localresponse; 
    try
    {

        //this.SaveFileStream(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[fileToPush.FileType].ToString() + "\\" + fileToPush.FileName, new MemoryStream(fileToPush.Content));
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {

            stream.CopyTo(fileStream); 
            fileStream.Flush(); 
            fileStream.Dispose();

        }

        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(filePath);
       ExtractFile(info);
       localresponse = "Successful";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        localresponse = ex.Message;

    }

    return localresponse;
}
```

Comment: which specific line of code results in exception being thrown?

Comment: Can you rename/delete the file before running your application? PS: The `Dispose` is not necessary as you are already using a `using`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..can i use close and Gc.Collect

Comment: Hi  Mr.Andrew i dont get you ..